How to make Edge and Chrome trust self-signed certificate?
Background:
I’m hosting a local server with multiple services on a Linux machine (Ubuntu 20.04) at myIP.
My NGINX configuration uses a self-signed SSL certificate to serve the following domains:
domain.local
api.domain.local
logs.domain.local
superset.domain.local

The self-signed certificate (domain.crt) was generated using the following commands:
openssl genrsa -out ./certs/domain.key 2048
openssl req -new -key ./certs/domain.key -out ./certs/domain.csr \
    -subj "/C=US/ST=State/L=City/O=Organization/CN=*.domain.local"
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in ./certs/domain.csr -signkey ./certs/domain.key -out ./certs/domain.crt

However, when accessing https://domain.local
in Microsoft Edge or Chrome, the browser marks the connection as "Not Secure."
What I have tried:
Verified the certificate was successfully imported into the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store.
Ensured DNS resolution is working correctly.
Pinging the domains (domain.local, api.domain.local, etc.) resolves to the correct IP.
Checked the NGINX logs, which show no SSL-related errors.
Confirmed the certificates domain.key and domain.crt are mounted correctly in the container.
Verified that NGINX starts successfully without any issues.
Accessing the application works fine over HTTPS, but the browser doesn’t trust the connection.
Environment:
Server OS: Ubuntu 20.04
Browser: Microsoft Edge, Chrome (latest version on Windows 11)
Local Network: All devices are on the same LAN
Question:
How can I make Microsoft Edge or Chrome trust the self-signed certificate for my local domains?
Is there a specific step I’m missing in configuring or importing the certificate?
Any help would be appreciated!

The wildcard certificates do not work on this way. You create certificate for *.domain.tld. Which mean this will work for all hosts in form something.domain.tld, it expect to have hostname before the domain. And will not server domain.tld because here domain is the hostname and .tld is the domain.
You can try to add SAN (Subject Alternative Name). But in your case (with wildcard certificate) IMHO this may not work (depend of the settings of CA).
Warning: Do not try to create certificate for *.tld because this will not work for something. domain.tld, will work for something.tld only.
The only solution is to explicitly list all the hosts in certificate via SAN

There are two problems here:

You've used the Common Name to hold the certificate's subject - this is deprecated in browsers (and other relying parties).  Instead, you need to add the subject to the Subject Alternative Name (SAN) extension instead (or in addition).

You cannot use *.domain.local for domain.local, only for sub-domains of domain.local.  You therefore need a certificate with two SAN entries - one for domain.local and another for *.domain.local.


Try a config, such as this (call it minimal.cfg):
prompt             = no
distinguished_name = req_dn
req_extensions     = req_ext

[ req_dn ]
commonName         = Local Web Service

[ req_ext ]
# basicContraints might be required for Firefox?
# basicConstraints = critical, CA:true
# Remove everything below this line if you don't need SAN.
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]
DNS.1 = domain.local
DNS.2 = *.domain.local

Then, create a self-signed certificate with:
openssl req -x509 -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -days 365 -keyout domain.key -out domain.cer -config minimal.cnf -extensions req_ext

You may have to tweak the above to suit your setup.

@RomeoNinov - what does Thawte say in that linked doc?

@RomeoNinov  - That's Thawte's opinion :-)  RFC 2818 Section 3.1 disagrees and discusses multiple dnsName entries with wildcards.  Also, the common Let's Encrypt certs will have a wildcard SAN.  I think that might be a commercial stance by Thawte.
